# My Windows 10 bluetooth doesn't have a button to turn on or off

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I've searched for similar problems that have happened to other people, but can't find a solution. On my device manager, I don't have the Bluetooth option for some reason, but in the Services app I can find everything Bluetooth-related (Bluetooth audio, Bluetooth support service, Bluetooth user support services) except I don't have the Bluetooth Handsfree Service. I am pretty sure I just don't have Bluetooth In my windows 10, but I am hoping there is a way to get it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don’t actually have Bluetooth, what do you expect to toggle?

Comment: If you don't have a BT device, you should use a USB BT device,  you will then be able to enable/disable it from the Action Center.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer does not have Bluetooth hardware. The services continue to run but do not use many resources. If you connect a Bluetooth device the services will manage it.